# Select relationship columns and query inside with method eloquent laravel

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-6

Using `with` method to retrieve relations I stuck here:

I have 3 tables, `news`, `users` and `news_user`:

```
users:
    id, name, email, is_admin, role_id, internal_id, timestamps

news:
    id, title, subtitle, slug, published, timestamps

news_user:
    id, user_id, news_id, action_id, timestamps
```

So as you can see I created this `news_user` as a pivot table and returning to my API with no problems.

```
News::where('slug', $slug)
        ->where('published', 1)
        ->with('users:id,name')
        ->firstOrFail();
```

It was working well, but I needed to add a query function to retrieve only the users that done an specific action. I was returning specific users columns and now it's returning all users columns because the query function don't give me an option to select the columns like before.

```
News::where('slug', $slug)
        ->where('published', 1)
        ->with(['users' => function($query){
                $query->where('action_id', 3);
            }])
        ->firstOrFail();
```

And even that I add `users:id,name` together this return all columns and I can't do `'users:id,name' => function..`

How can I retrieve only this columns?

P.S: I'm using laravel 6.2

Comment: If you add `$query->select('id,name');` inside `function($query)` it works?

Comment: Did you solve it?

Comment: no, return just `"\"id,name\"": "id,name",`

Comment: the main problem is there's some columns with information about user, like `is_admin`, `internal_id`, `timestamps`, etc, I just dont want return these informations :(